# constructing javascript variable names at runtime

Tags: javascript

```
someFunction(link) {
  someOtherFunction('div' + link);
}
```

By calling someFunction("Test"), the string "divTest" gets passed to someOtherFunction(). But I want the value of the variable "divTest" to be passed.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make your variables members of an object. Then you can use `[]` to access the objects members using a string:

```
var byname = {
  divabc: ...,
  divxyz: ...
};

function someFunction(link) {
  someOtherFunction(byname['div'+link]);
}

someFunction('abc'); // calls someOtherFunction(byname.divabc)
```

Answer (score 8):

For this kind of dynamic construction/access of variable names you should use the alternative object notation where:

```
object.member === object["member"]
```

This way you could construct your variable name as a string and use it inside square brackets for accessing object members.

Answer (score 3):

`eval` will do this, but it's usually indicative of some other problem with the program when you want to synthesize identifiers like this. As Ionut says it's better to use the `[]` notation. I like to link to [this](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) whenever questions like this come up.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to accomplish this with the '[eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)' function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var divFoo = "bar";
function someFunction(link) {
    someOtherFunction(this['div' + link]);
}
function someOtherFunction(value) {
    alert(value);
}
someFunction("Foo");
```

Answer (score -1):

As wybiral said, all you need is eval:

```
someFunction(link) {
  someOtherFunction(eval('(div' + link + ')');
}
```

Basically what it does is evaluates the contents of a string as code. Obviously eval is a dangerous little tool since it allows executing arbitrary code so take care when using it.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the inner most set of parenthesis?

Comment: RyOnLife: They don't serve any specific purpose in this example but it is good practice to put all your eval strings in parentheses. Here's why: http://techiella.wordpress.com/2008/09/04/javascript-eval/