# Using a for loop with objects to print out properties of each unique object

Tags: javascript, oop, object, for-loop

I am trying something new and I am having issues with my current idea.  I am still new and trying to grasp the basics of using objects so I might be completely off base with this but I thought I might ask you all if what I am doing has any chance of working.

```
// first we can make the instructor
function Rabbit(adjective) {
    this.adjective = adjective;
    this.describeMyself = function() {
        console.log("I am a " + this.adjective + " rabbit");
    };
}

// now we can easily make all of our rabbits
var rabbit1 = new Rabbit("fluffy");
var rabbit2 = new Rabbit("happy");
var rabbit3 = new Rabbit("sleepy");

for (i=1;i<=3;i++){
    //console.log("rabbit"+i);
    var tempRabbit = "rabbit"+i;
    console.log(tempRabbit.adjective);
}
```

I want to use the for loop to add the number to each rabbit object i created and then print out the adjective it has passed into it.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Use an array to store the 3 objects instead of creating 3 independent objects.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576055/constructing-javascript-variable-names-at-runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most people store rabbits in arrays. This makes it much easier to manage the growing population of these marvelous creatures.

Here's an example:

```
var rabbitArray = [
    new Rabbit("fluffy"),
    new Rabbit("happy"),
    new Rabbit("sleepy")
];

for (var i=0;i<rabbitArray.length;i++) {
    console.log(rabbitArray[i].adjective);
}
```

You can also push new rabbits into the array you've got. There's special method for that:

```
rabbitArray.push(new Rabbit("stubborn"));
```

If you need more information on how to use arrays to simplify the management of your stock, refer to this documentation: [Javascript Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Thank you, I figured an array would be the best way to do this, but I was just trying to see if there was a way to use the combination of concatenating the string with the "i" variable and access the properties that way.  Appreciate all the quick answers guys.

Comment: That is also a possibility (see other answers), however if you try doing that that - never risk showing your code to other developers... well, unless you have a life insurance.

Comment: I am just trying out different things while doing the lessons from codeacademy.com.  Thanks again for the helpful advice.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
> for (i=1;i<=3;i++){
>     //console.log("rabbit"+i);
>     var tempRabbit = "rabbit"+i;
>     console.log(tempRabbit.adjective);
> }
```

the value of *tempRabbit* is a string, and strings don't have an *adjective* method. Since your Rabbit objects are assigned to global variables, you can access them as named properties of the global object. In browsers, the *window* object is essentially the global object so you could use square bracket notation:

```
console.log(window[tempRabbit].adjective);
```

However, probably better to put your Rabbits in an array and access them as members (per other answers).

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval with:

```
eval('var tempRabbit = rabbit'+i+';');
```

This will create and evaluate the string. 
You have to know that some people find `eval` awful.

Comment: Almost all find eval to be awful :-)

Comment: Some? No one with reasonable knowledge of javascript would recommend that approach given the many, more suitable options.

Comment: Well for knowledge it can't be bad to talk about this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array, and then access it by index.

```
var rabbits=[];
rabbits[0]= new Rabbit("fluffy");
rabbits[1] = new Rabbit("happy");
rabbits[2] = new Rabbit("sleepy");
```